# IE9 not showing ul li ul submenu all other browsers IE before do

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html-lists, submenu

i did not find exactly this problem in the other questions

only in IE9 my submenu and all css on ul li ul does not show .
 It works correctly in IE6 7 8, firefox , safari, chrome, opera,..

so i have a part of css like this : 
...

## nav ul li:hover {text-decoration:underline; color:green;}

## nav ul li a:hover {text-decoration:underline;color:red;}

...
my menu (list) goes like this :
"..

- menu choise 1
- submenu title

  - Submenu choise 1

"..

i have the red color bur nor the green !! and the real problem is that i don't see the submenu!!

thanks for helping,

Ber lingo

Comment: Post a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com to make it easier for someone to help you